# NSArray vs NSDictionary - Which is better for string searching

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am going to store a list of values in a plist and retrieve them. The list will be searched for a value (which may change each time) each time the search method is called. There will probably be about 10 values in the list.

Is either NSArray or NSDictionary better for a search?

I think that NSArray is more appropriate because right now, at least, I don't have a key-value pair data set, just a list.

Could someone confirm and perhaps offer the best method for search the array?

Thanks

Comment: If you are only going to have 10 items it just doesn't make any sense to try and implement something to be more efficient. Suppose you can search the array in 1/1000000 of a second, but the dictionary is faster at 1/100000 second. What difference does it make? Just do the simplest thing and only worry about this if you have tens of thousands of items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is conceptual:

If you have a **list of value**, you **mustn't use NSDictionary**. The appropriate *data structure* is `NSArray` or `NSSet`.

Basically, `NSSet` is **faster** than `NSArray`, because doesn't have to consider the order etc.

So if you need just to **search a value** and the **order doesn't matter**, **the best data structure to use** is `NSSet` (or `NSMutableSet` if you need it mutable).

Comment: Thanks Matteo, I'm going to try NSSet. Sounds faster and since I don't have a key alongside my value, this sounds most appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries will be faster for searching than arrays because the keys are hashed. With an array the system has to check all the items until it finds a match.

The docs for NSSet say that sets are faster in testing for membership than arrays. If you don't have values to store for each key, the best option might be to store the data to your plist as an array. At runtime, read the array, and load it's contents into a set using the NSSet class method `setWithArray:`

If your data sets are large (many thousands of items) I would suggest doing performance testing with dictionaries where all the values are NSNull against an NSSet. (With a dictionary you'd use `objectForKey:` and with a set you'd use the `containsObject:` method

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring timing the best option would be to use an NSArray.  NSArray has all sorts of useful methods such as

```
(NSArray *)filteredArrayUsingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate
```

and

```
(NSIndexSet *)indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:(BOOL (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))predicate
```

that you can use for searching within an array.

Comment: also sets have the methods like this...and are better than arrays in this case.